# How to force NEST to use attribute mappings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Ok, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I spent a day browsing documentation and trying 3 different NEST versions, and the end result is the same.

Basically when I use the REST api of Elasticsearch to create the the mappings for a type, I can then use a GET request on my mappings and I receive exactly what I want:

```
"properties": {
   "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "basic_date"
   },
   "id": {
      "type": "long",
      "index": "no"
   },
   "name": {
      "type": "string"
   },
   "slug": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "no"
   }
}
```

However, if I start from scratch, and use the following class in c#:

```
[Number(Index = NonStringIndexOption.No)]
public long Id { get; set; }
[String(Name = "name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[String(Name = "slug", Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
public string Slug { get; set; }
[Date(Format = "dd-MM-yyyy", Index = NonStringIndexOption.No)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and create and fill the index as such:

```
node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.DefaultIndex("searchable-items");
//retrieve stuff from relational db
client.IndexMany(allItemsRetrievedFromRelDb);
```

my types default to the following (basically disregarding all attribute values, except for Name=)

```
"date": {
   "type": "date",
   "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
},
"id": {
   "type": "long"
},
"name": {
   "type": "string"
},
"slug": {
   "type": "string"
}
```

Basically what I'm hoping to achieve is:

1. A date format of type "basic_date"
2. Only "name" should be analyzed and search-able
3. Eventually, a custom analyzer for the "name"

My question is - what am I doing wrong, and why is NEST disregarding whatever I put in the attributes? Current code is v2.4.4, although I also tried the 5.0.0 pre-release (slightly different syntax there, but same result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the attribute mapping to take effect, you need to tell Elasticsearch about the mapping, either when you're creating the index with `.CreateIndex()` or after you create the index and before you index any documents, with `.Map()`.

Here's an example to demonstrate using NEST 2.4.4

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "searchable-items";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            // specify the default index to use if
            // 1. no index is specified on the request
            // 2. no index can be inferred from the C# POCO type 
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);;

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
                // map MyDocument, letting
                // NEST infer the mapping from the property types
                // and attributes applied to them
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );

    var docs = new[] {
        new MyDocument
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "name 1",
            Date = new DateTime(2016,08,26),
            Slug = "/slug1"
        },
        new MyDocument
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "name 2",
            Date = new DateTime(2016,08,27),
            Slug = "/slug2"
        }
    };

    client.IndexMany(docs);
}

public class MyDocument
{
    [Number(Index = NonStringIndexOption.No)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [String(Name = "slug", Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "dd-MM-yyyy", Index = NonStringIndexOption.No)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

[The Automapping documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html) has more details on how you can control the mapping for a POCO type using [the fluent API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#auto-mapping-with-overrides) and [the visitor pattern (for applying conventions).](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#applying-conventions-through-the-visitor-pattern)

Comment: This solved it, thank you. Just one word of advice for others reading this - don't use a DateTime property if you don't intend to expect time on elasticsearch's end - it contains time and it breaks the request. Use a string with the Date attribute on it.

Comment: @nikovn - I'm assuming that means i can mark a string property with a Number or Boolean attribute as well?  If I have a DTO class that i use to import a csv file with and want to verify if the string property actually has an number value before i send it off to ElasticSearch, i should be able to specify that it's a Number with the Number attribute rather than it being inferred by the property's type, is that correct?

Comment: @FrankTzanabetis you should use the correct Elasticsearch type for the value that you're going to send to Elasticsearch e.g. sending `"1"` is a string, so should be indexed as a string, although mapping it explicitly to `integer`, Elasticsearch can be forced to coerce the string to integer by setting `coerce: true` on the mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#number-params. The attributes and fluent mapping are largely for providing additional options to field mappings; you can do what you've asked but could be setting up for issues in future :)